# Catch an Exception inside Kotlin callbackFlow builder

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a consumer that looks like this:

```
// ItemConsumer.kt
try {
    job = itemService
            .connect()
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
            .catch { e ->
                throw e
            }
            .onEach {
                // Update UI for each item collected
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
} catch (e : Exception) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

And I have a producer that looks this:

```
// ItemService.kt (Producer)
fun connect():Flow<Item> = callbackFlow {
    check(1 == 0) // This is expected to throw an IllegalStateException
}
```

I understand that the .catch { } will handle any issues that would arise inside the Consumer's .collect { } or the .onEach { } block. But how can I throw the exception that happens inside the callbackFlow { } builder so that it may be caught in the .catch { } of the consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The exception will never be thrown by the flow builder function. `Flow`s are cold, meaning that no code is executed until collect is called. You'll always build a flow successfully even if the execution of collection yields to an exception.

Answer (score 4):

`catch` operator [catches only upstream exceptions (that is an exception from all the operators above catch, but not below it)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#transparent-catch). In your code, any exception in `onEach` or `collect` (via `launchIn`) won't be catched. You need to move this operator below `onEach` to catch *all* exceptions.

This operator [catches exceptions in the flow completion](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html). It could be possible to catch them in `callbackFlow` builder only if the flow completes normally or exceptionally. As [@SomeRandomITBoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179321/2668136) said it will never be thrown by the flow builder. But since this builder uses a [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) under the hood, in order to complete the flow exceptionally, you have to [`close`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/close.html?query=abstract%20fun%20close(cause:%20Throwable?%20=%20null):%20Boolean) it manually with non-null cause:

```
abstract fun close(cause: Throwable? = null): Boolean
```

Keep in mind that might violates transparency: "Flows must be *transparent to exceptions* and it is a violation of the exception transparency to emit values in the `flow { ... }` builder from inside of a `try/catch` block". I might wrong but I think, since you use `catch`, this "preserves this exception transparency and allows encapsulation of its exception handling".

So the consumer could be as follows:

```
job = itemService.connect()
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    .onEach {
        // update UI
    }
    .catch { e ->
        // handle exception
    }
    .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

And the producer should close with an exception like this:

```
fun connect(): Flow<Item> = callbackFlow {
    try {
        check(1 == 0) // throws an exception
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        close(e) // close manually with exception
    }
}
```